# Merge two lists on index

Tags: java, arrays, list, object

I have two lists containing the same type of objects. Each object has an int, a string and some other stuff where the int is its index.

Here is the object that both lists are holding:

```
public class ListElement
{
    private int index;
    private String data;
    private String some;
    private String other;
    private String stuff;

    // gets, sets...

}
```

What i want is to take List A's index and "some other stuff" and replace its string "data" with the one from List B. The one it takes from List B should match the index of List A. I hope this is understandable.

EDIT: It should be noted that the index int inside the object has nothing to do with the actual position of the object in the list. Its for other porpuses

Comment: So nested for loops?  Iterate over ListA, find matching element of ListB (if any) and do the operation.

Comment: If we want the indices to match, nesting shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Is this the index with respect to its containing array, or just a coincidental int field called index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: You mentioned that the `index` field of your `ListElement` has no relationship with its actual place in its containing List.

You just happen to have a field with a random name that you want to compare both list on (join on).  This solution uses nested loops to compare every element in one list with every element in the other list.

```
for (int iA = 0; iA < listA.size(); iA++) //iterate over listA
{
    ListElement currentElement = listA.get(iA);
    for (int iB = 0; iB < listB.size(); iB++) //iterate over listB
    {
        ListElement other = listB.get(iB); 
        if (other.index == currentElement.index) //compare the elements
        {
            //do stuff
            currentElement.setData(other.getData()); 
            break; //if only want first match
        }         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your both list have the same number of elements, you could do something like:

```
ListElement sourceElement, destElement;
for (int i =0; i<list1.size(); i++) {
    sourceElement = list1.get(0);
    destElement = list2.get(0);
    sourceElement.setData(destElement.getData());
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first idea is probably not the brightest but I'll come to that later.

```
For (ListElement e : ListA) {
  For (ListElement le : ListB) {
    if (e.getIndex() = le.getIndex()) {
      e.setData(le.getData());
    }
  }
}
```

So this is my first shot for what you wrote, but it's probably not the easiest way. To make it simpler and faster you could implement the interface `Comparable` and use [sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)), i this case you access the List elements by the index in ListElement (assuming you assure the indices are complete from 1..n).
My favored solution would be to use some kind of [maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to store the index as key, and the ListElement as value, then it's just `MapA.get(i).setData(MapB.get(i).getData())` This is fool-prove, as long as for every item in MapA there is an according item in MapB with the same index.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match on the `index` field on the `ListItem` object, try this:

```
for (ListItem listItemA : listA) {
    for (ListItem listItemB : listB) {
        if (listItemB.getIndex() == listItemA.getIndex()) {
            listItemA.setData(listItemB.getData());
        }
    }
}
```

If you're interested in matching based on index within the `List` objects, try

```
for (int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++) {
    listA.get(i).setData(listB.get(i).getData());
}
```